# PHP equivalent question

Tags: php

What is the PHP equivalent to `<!--#echo var="HTTP_REFERER" -->` and what code language  is `<!--#echo var="HTTP_REFERER" -->`.

Comment: The notation you've found is called server side includes. There is an Apache module for that. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers have noted, the equivalent directive is:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
```

But, to answer your other question, the language you quote in your question is ['Server Side Includes'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes), or, at least, *seems* to be.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

More server related information is also in the [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array